# Regex to match key=(value, value) format

Tags: javascript, regex, string, match

I'm trying to turn a string with some information about changes in values into an object with these information separated (or an array with them).

The string I receive is something like this format, representing the changes:

`{xRate=(250.0, 260.0), yValue=(1.51, 1.54)}`.

I would like to get something like

`[['xRate', '(250.0, 260.0)'],['yValue', '(1.51, 1.54)']]`

or at least have a regex to work since I can't figure it out.

I tried

```
/,*\s*(.*)=\s*(.*)/
```

but it creates group 1 as `test=(23, 34), var` and group 2 as `(true , false)` in `test=(23, 34), var=(true , false)`, for example.

Thanks in advance for any help!

(Also, if you know any great resource to understand regex more I'd love to see it then I learn this for good haha)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
const regex = /(\w+)=\((.+?)\)/g;
const str = `{xRate=(250.0, 260.0), yValue=(1.51, 1.54), test=(23, 34), var=(true , false)}`;
while ((match = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
  console.log(`first group: ${match[1]} and second: ${match[2]}`);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Alireza! This approach solved my issue and I could advance in the task :)

Answer (score 3):

A regex which targets the OP's problem as specific as it was presented through the OP's example code does target up to two `key=(value ...)` patterns which are enclosed by curly braces ... and might look like this ... [`/\{\s*(?<key1>[^=\s*]+)\s*=\s*(?<value1>\([^)]+\))\s*(?:,\s*(?<key2>[^=\s*]+)\s*=\s*(?<value2>\([^)]+\))\s*)?\}/g`](https://regex101.com/r/gJoFH7/1) ... but also would equally match ...

- `{ key=(value), key=(value, value, ...) }`
- `{ key=(value, value), key=(value) }`
- `{ key=(value, value) }`
- `{ key=(value) }`

```js
const sampleText = `{xRate=(250.0, 260.0)  ,  yValue  =(1.51, 1.54)} ... { xRate  =  (250.0, 260.0)  }
... { yValue=(1.51, 1.54) } ... {  xRate = ( 250.0 , 260.0), yValue=(1.51, 1.54) }`;

// [https://regex101.com/r/gJoFH7/1]
const regXKeyValueMaxTwice = (/\{\s*(?<key1>[^=\s*]+)\s*=\s*(?<value1>\([^)]+\))\s*(?:,\s*(?<key2>[^=\s*]+)\s*=\s*(?<value2>\([^)]+\))\s*)?\}/g)

const keyValueToArrayEntryFormat = (match, key1, value1, key2, value2) =>
  (key2 && value2)
    ? `[['${ key1 }', '${ value1 }'], ['${ key2 }', '${ value2 }']]`
    : `[['${ key1 }', '${ value1 }']]`;

console.log(
  sampleText + '\n\n => \n\n',

  sampleText.replace(regXKeyValueMaxTwice, keyValueToArrayEntryFormat)
);

console.log('\nadditional regX logging ...\n\n');

console.log([
  ...sampleText.matchAll(regXKeyValueMaxTwice)
  ]
);
console.log([
  ...sampleText.matchAll(regXKeyValueMaxTwice)
  ].map(({ groups }) => groups)
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

But a more generic approach has the freedom of dealing with an unlimited number of `key = (value[, value[, ...]])` (sub)pattern sequences wich are all enclosed by curly braces like ... `{ key=(value), key=(value, value),.. key=(value, value) ... }`.

Thus, in order to transform the above format/pattern into ... `[["key", "(value)"], ["key", "(value, value)"],.. ["key", "(value, value)"] ...]` a regex can not anymore predict the frequency/occurrence of such a base pattern, but it can capture additional flags which allow to later indicate whether such a pattern was opened by `{` or continued by `,` or terminated by `}`.

An also simpler and cleaner regex then might look like this ... [`/(?<sequenceFlag>[{,])\s*(?<key>\w+)\s*=\s*(?<value>\([^)]+\))\s*(?<terminatingFlag>\}?)/g`](https://regex101.com/r/gJoFH7/2) ... and an implementation of the according replacement then might come close to that ...

```js
const sampleText = `{xRate=(250.0, 260.0)  ,  yValue  =(1.51, 1.54)} ... { xRate  =  (250.0, 260.0)  }

... { yValue=(1.51, 1.54) } ... {  xRate = ( 250.0 , 260.0), yValue=(1.51, 1.54) }

{ xRate = ( 250.0, 260.0 ) ,yValue=(1.51,1.54), zItem =( foo, bar,baz) } ... {xRate=(250.0,260.0)}`;

// [https://regex101.com/r/gJoFH7/2]
const regXKeyValueTemplate = (/(?<sequenceFlag>[{,])\s*(?<key>\w+)\s*=\s*(?<value>\([^)]+\))\s*(?<terminatingFlag>\}?)/g)

const keyValueToArrayEntryFormat = ((match, sequenceFlag, key, value, terminatingFlag) => {
  const concatEntry = (sequenceFlag === '{') && '[[' || ', [';
  const closeSequence = (terminatingFlag === '}') && ']' || '';
  return `${ concatEntry }'${ key }', '${ value }']${ closeSequence }`;
});

console.log(
  sampleText + '\n\n => \n\n',

  sampleText.replace(regXKeyValueTemplate, keyValueToArrayEntryFormat)
);

console.log('\nadditional regX logging ...\n\n');

console.log([
  ...sampleText.matchAll(regXKeyValueTemplate)
  ]
);
console.log([
  ...sampleText.matchAll(regXKeyValueTemplate)
  ].map(({ groups }) => groups)
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

regex sources:

- [regular-expressions.info :: Quick Start](https://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html)
- [javascript.info :: Capturing groups](https://javascript.info/regexp-groups)
- [MDN :: JavaScript Guide :: Regular expressions :: Groups and ranges](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Groups_and_Ranges)
- [MDN :: JavaScript reference :: String :: replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation and the resources you sent, Peter! It helped me understand better about how the patterns would work and I didn't know about this pattern of extracting variables from the regex matches.